# Anyone has experience with OHLC bars in quasardB?

Tags: time-series, quantitative-finance

I would like to use quasardb to generate minute bars of realtime tick by tick market data

Any suggested or recommended design and implementation ? I have a portfolio of 200 instruments

Comment: Could you be more precise, please? What language do you want to use? How does your input data look like, if any?

Comment: Hi,
looking to use Python , input is a timeseries of execution ( time, price, volume )
The series update possibly 1000 times or more per minute